# Необычная сортировка массива php

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив:

```
 [0] => 
        (
            [id] => 254
            [fid] => 31
        )
 [1] =>
        (
            [id] => 312
            [fid] => 29
        )
 [2] =>
        (
            [id] => 245
            [fid] => 30
        )
 [3] =>
        (
            [id] => 233
            [fid] => 30
        )
 [4] =>
        (
            [id] => 344
            [fid] => 31
        )
 [5] =>
        (
            [id] => 342
            [fid] => 31
        )
        ...
```

и т.д.

Можно ли сделать такую сортировку, чтобы первым элементом был fid c 29, затем fid с 30, затем fid c 31, потом опять c 29, 30, 31, и т.д.

Спасибо!

Comment: перебрать массив и переложить элементы в новый в нужном порядке. искомую идешку хранить в переменной и менять в процессе.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ['id'=>4,'fid'=>13],
    ['id'=>5,'fid'=>14],
    ['id'=>6,'fid'=>15],
    ['id'=>1,'fid'=>12],
    ['id'=>2,'fid'=>12],
    ['id'=>3,'fid'=>13],

    ];

$sortedArr=[];
foreach($arr as $row){
    $sortedArr[$row['fid']][]=$row;
}
ksort($sortedArr);
$sortedArr=array_values($sortedArr);
$countSortedArr = count($sortedArr);

$result=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    if($sortedArr[$i%$countSortedArr]){
        $result[]=array_pop($sortedArr[$i%$countSortedArr]);
    }else{
        $i--;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```